# Which annotation need to use for unique constraint in JPA entity, unique=true or @UniqueConstraints at class level with single unique column

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have some existing project and used both unique =true at column level and @UniqueConstraints at entity class level for the same column as below. I am currently doing code refactor so need suggestion to improve the code.

```
@Table(name = "sales_order", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "order_no"))
public class SalesOrder implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long                 serialVersionUID = 6008509031685325038L;

    //primary key column with some other columns 
    
    @Column(name = "order_no", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String orderNo;
}
```

We can not use both for the same unique column right ?
In the above code, which one is the best to use or define unique constraint?
I would say if it's single column unique then can use unique=true at column level and if unique key contains multiple columns then use @UniqueConstraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Best" is obviously subjective, but your proposed approach works well.
And it describes the only limitation, forcing the use of one over the other.

> I would say if it's single column unique then can use `unique=true` at column level and if unique key contains multiple columns then use `@UniqueConstraints`.

Of course, one might argue for always using `@UniqueConstraints` in order to make the code more uniform.
But that is really a matter of code style.

Comment: any issue if we use both annotation for the the single column as shown in the code ? OrderNo column used at column level unique attribute and also at class UniqueConstraint annotation.

Comment: I would avoid that. Even if it works ok right now, you might easily get, exceptions, duplicate indexes in the future, plus if someone wants to change the constraint in the code they now have two places to fix.